# Android running out of memory

Tags: android, debugging, memory-management

Below I am showing the first and second activities. The first one is just to show what the baseline memory is. My question is: **what is going on in the second activity that is allocating so much memory?!**

It should not be working so hard and I can't figure out what it is that is allocating so much memory at that steady pace. It continues to allocate at the rate shown below for the second screen until it runs out. Then I guess the GC gets called and re-allocates memory. Then the memory keeps getting allocated until it runs out again and again.

**First Activity Screen:**

[image: First Screen]

**First Activities Memory:**

[image: Memory for First Screen]

**Second Activity Screen:**
No buttons have been pressed yet and nothing is being recorded. SignalStrengthListener checks for changes in the LTE parameters and updates the UI once per second. But the memory is going out of control.

[image: Second Screen]

**Second Activity Memory:**

[image: Memory for Second Screen]

Here is my code for the Second activity and its layout:

**Second.java**

```
public class Second extends Activity implements Runnable {

    public static SignalStrengthListener signalStrengthListener;
    public static TelephonyManager tm;
    List<CellInfo> cellInfoList;

    public static TextView lteRsrp;
    public static TextView lteRsrq, lteCqi;
    public static TextView cellPciTextView;
    EditText offsetText;

    Button startButton, offsetButton;
    public static int cellPci = 0;
    public static String ltestr;
    public static String[] parts;
    public static String mydate;
    public static double offset = 0.0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        run();
        setupUI();
        setupButton();

    }

    private void setupUI() {
        lteRsrp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lteRsrp);
        lteRsrq = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lteRsrq);
        lteCqi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lteCqi);
        cellPciTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cellPciTextView);
        offsetText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.offsetText);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        offsetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.offsetButton);


        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        parts[9] = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(parts[9]) + offset);

                        if (Double.parseDouble(parts[9]) == 2147483647) {
                            parts[9] = "-141";
                        }
                        if (Integer.parseInt(parts[10]) == 2147483647) {
                            parts[10] = "-21";
                        }
                        if (Integer.parseInt(parts[12]) == 2147483647) {
                            parts[12] = "-20";
                        }

                        lteRsrp.setText(String.valueOf(parts[9]));
                        lteRsrq.setText(String.valueOf(parts[10]));
                        lteCqi.setText(String.valueOf(parts[12]));
                        cellPciTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cellPci));
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1000);

    }

    private void setupButton() {
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Third.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        offsetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                offset = Double.parseDouble(offsetText.getText().toString());
                Log.d("TAG", "????????????????????????????????????????????????  offset value is = " + offset);
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Moves the current Thread into the background
//        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

        //start the signal strength listener
        signalStrengthListener = new SignalStrengthListener();
        ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

    }

    public class SignalStrengthListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrength signalStrength) {

            ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

            tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            ltestr = signalStrength.toString();
            parts = ltestr.split(" ");

            try {
                cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
                for (CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfoList) {

//                        Log.d("TAG", "cellInfoList size = " + cellInfoList.size() + " +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

                    if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                        // cast to CellInfoLte and call all the CellInfoLte methods you need
                        // Gets the LTE PCI: (returns Physical Cell Id 0..503, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                        cellPci = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getPci();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
//                    Log.d("SignalStrength", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ null array spot 3: " + e);
            }

            mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);

        }
    }

}
```

**second_activity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffdc1d">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE RSRP"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#a71b1b"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:id="@+id/lteRsrq"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE RSRQ"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#a71b1b"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lteRsrp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#075f09"
        android:id="@+id/cellPciTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lteRsrq"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lteRsrq"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE PCI"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#075f09"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cellPciTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/lteCqi"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cellPciTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cellPciTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="= LTE CQI"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:background="#ffdc1d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lteCqi"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textColor="#ffdc1d"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        android:background="#f91616"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press the START button to begin recording"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#f91616"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Set offset"
        android:id="@+id/offsetButton"
        android:textColor="#ffdc1d"
        android:background="#f91616"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="83dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/offsetText"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/offsetButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lteCqi"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use allocation tracking or a heap dump to determine what is going on.

Comment: I have done that but I can't make much sense of it the tracking or the dump. I see a lot of nested calls to the SignalStrengthListener. I am pretty sure that is the culprit, but I can't figure out a fix.

Comment: Well, try calling `listen()` only once, rather than once up front and then once every time the `onSignalStrengthsChanged()` callback is invoked. You might also consider only calling `getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)` once (rather than once up front and twice on every callback) and only calling `getDateTimeInstance()` once (instead of once on every callback).

Comment: I have 6 threads, but thread 1 (UI) is 98.69%. When I dig into it there are a ton of calls to onSignalStrengthsChanged(). It gets called about 200 times/sec. And I don't know how to change that, or if I can.

Comment: Calling `listen()` only once may help, depending on how `TelephonyManager` implements its listener management. You may be experiencing geometric growth on your number of `onSignalStrengthsChanged()` calls. Beyond that, I can see where that method might get called frequently in general. Your objective should be to do as little work as possible in that method, and in particular to not allocate any objects in that method.

Comment: If I take out one of the `listen()`s then it does not work and I get nulls. Same with `getSystemService`. And I need a time stamp for each entry. But thanks for pointing that out because here I don't need it since I'm not recording it yet. I'll play around more with what you have suggested to see if I can get it to work without the double calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I think you got yourself into a bit of an infinite loop there.

[The docs for `listen()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29) say:

> At registration, and when a specified telephony state changes, the telephony manager invokes the appropriate callback method on the listener object and passes the current (updated) values.

So, what happened was you called `listen()`, which called `onSignalStrengthsChanged()`, which called `listen()`, which called `onSignalStrengthsChanged()`, which called `listen()`, which called `onSignalStrengthsChanged()`, which called `listen()`, which called `onSignalStrengthsChanged()`, which called `listen()`, which called `onSignalStrengthsChanged()`, ...

By removing the `listen()` from inside the `onSignalStrengthsChanged()` method, you removed the infinite loop.

Comment: You're amazing! Thanks! I was wrong, I took out the listen() inside of onSignalStrengthsChanged and it still works, but more importantly my memory plateaus! I no longer run out of memory!!! I'd been staring at that for a month and I read the Docs but didn't understand it. Having a second pair of eyes on the code is invaluable.